# Conversion incompatibility between timestamp type in Glue and in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I want to run a simple sql select of timestamp fields from my data using **spark sql (pyspark)**.
However, all the timestamp fields appear as 1970-01-19 10:45:37.009 .
So looks like I have some **conversion incompatibility between timestamp in Glue and in Spark**.

I'm running with pyspark, and I have the glue catalog configuration so I get my database schema from Glue. In both Glue and the spark sql dataframe these columns appear with timestamp type.

However, it looks like when I read the parquet files from s3 path, the event_time column (for example) is of type long and when I get its data, I get a correct event_time as epoch in milliseconds = **1593938489000**. So I can convert it and get the actual datetime.

But when I run spark.sql , the event_time column gets timestamp type but it isn’t useful and missing precision. So I get this = **1970-01-19 10:45:37.009** .
When I run the same sql query in Athena, the timestamp field looks fine so my schema in Glue looks correct.

Is there a way to overcome it?
I didn't manage to find any spark.sql configurations that solved it.

Comment: can you please check..and comment

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 1970, due to incorrect way of formatting. Please give a try below code to convert long to UTC timestamp

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('timestamp_col_original', F.lit('1593938489000'))
df = df.withColumn('timestamp_col', (F.col('timestamp_col_original') / 1000).cast(T.TimestampType()))
df.show()
```

While converting : 1593938489000 I was getting below

```
timestamp_col_original|      timestamp_col|
+----------------------+-------------------+
|         1593938489000|2020-07-05 08:41:29|
|         1593938489000|2020-07-05 08:41:29|
|         1593938489000|2020-07-05 08:41:29|
|         1593938489000|2020-07-05 08:41:29|
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It didn't help. F.col('timestamp_col_original') is of timestamp type already in the schema, so I must do a conversion to T.LongType() before multiplying it by 1000 (in my case, I need to multiply and not divide because it looks like I'm losing precision). I do get the timestamp but all the timestamps look the same since it loses the precisions.

Comment: Can you please provide how the sample data looks like ? This becomes easy for understanding

Comment: This is the timestamp that I get when I run `df.show(1, False)`: `1970-01-19 10:48:55.073`

Comment: In the parquet itself, this is the type of the same column: `INT64 SNAPPY` . The value is: `1594140233000`

Comment: It looks like there's a parser issue between the data in parquet (stored as int64/long), and the **pyspark parser** which doesn't manage to read it correctly (when you run spark sql). The Athena parser manages to get the data correctly.